# Why can't I add a comment?

Tags: support, comments

I asked two Star Trek questions a while ago and I'm trying to comment back. For some reason I can't add a comment. Any help?

Comment: You must have accidentally created two accounts, if you can find the 'other' one, then you can [Merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Answer (score 17):

For **commenting anywhere**, you need [50 reputation points](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). (This equates to 5 upvotes on answers or questions, so you should be able to pick up those points fairly quickly if you have good content to contribute.)

For **commenting on your own posts, or on answers to your own questions**, there's no reputation requirement - you should be able to do this. If this is what you're trying to do and failing, then perhaps for some reason your account isn't associated with the questions you asked? I can only see [one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176276/31394) in your account history, but you mention that you asked two. (Could you provide a link to the other one?) If you asked the questions using two different accounts and you need to **merge accounts**, you can do that by following the instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

In general, the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) has most of the info you need about the basic workings of the site, but you can always feel free to [ask on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you still need help. (The [main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com) is only for questions about sci-fi or fantasy; **questions *about* the site should be asked here on meta** instead.)